# EncodeException "The serialized GlobalReference has type PointerType"

Tags: haskell, llvm

As a CS student, I am asked to write a compiler in a functional language with LLVM. I chose Haskell, despite the fact that I am very new to it and that I don't understand everything in source code examples, that's why my code may looks disgracious.

Before really beginning my project, I wanted to play a little bit with LLVM's Haskell bindings and make a function that call another which returns the difference between the two integers passed as parameters.

When running the code, I have the following exception :

> EncodeException "The serialized GlobalReference has type PointerType {pointerReferent = FunctionType {resultType = IntegerType {typeBits = 32}, argumentTypes = [IntegerType {typeBits = 32},IntegerType {typeBits = 32}], isVarArg = False}, pointerAddrSpace = AddrSpace 0} but should have type IntegerType {typeBits = 32}

And I really don't understand what is wrong with my code.

Here is my complete source code, thanks for your help.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where


import Control.Monad.Except

-- Pretty Printer

import LLVM.Pretty (ppllvm, ppll)

import LLVM.Module
import LLVM.Context
import LLVM.Module

-- AST
import LLVM.AST
import qualified LLVM.AST as AST
import LLVM.AST.Global
import LLVM.AST.CallingConvention
import LLVM.AST.Constant as Kokai
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B


int :: Type
int = IntegerType 32

defAdd :: Definition
defAdd = GlobalDefinition functionDefaults
  { name = Name "subbing"
  , parameters =
      ( [ Parameter int (Name "a") []
        , Parameter int (Name "b") [] ]
      , False )
  , returnType = int
  , basicBlocks = [block]
  }
  where

block :: BasicBlock
block = BasicBlock
    (Name "entry")
    [ Name "result" :=
      AST.Sub False
      False
      (LocalReference int (Name "a"))
      (LocalReference int (Name "b"))
      [] ]
    (Do $ Ret (Just (LocalReference int (Name "result"))) [])

foo :: Definition
foo = GlobalDefinition functionDefaults
  { name = Name "random_func"
  , parameters = ([], False)
  , returnType = int
  , basicBlocks = [calli]
  }
  where
calli :: BasicBlock
calli = BasicBlock
            (Name "entry")
            [Name "res" :=
             Call
                Nothing
                C
                []
                (Right $ ConstantOperand $ GlobalReference int "subbing")
                [(ConstantOperand $ Int 32 10, []),
                (ConstantOperand $ Int 32 7, [])]
                []
                []
                    ]
            (Do $ Ret (Just (ConstantOperand $ Int 32 10)) [])
            --(Do $ Ret (Just (LocalReference int (Name "res"))) [])

astModule :: AST.Module
astModule = defaultModule
  { moduleName = "my-module"
  , moduleDefinitions = [defAdd, foo]
  }

nimoft :: IO B.ByteString
nimoft = withContext $ \context ->
    withModuleFromAST context astModule $ \m -> do
      llstr <- moduleLLVMAssembly m
      B.putStrLn llstr
      return llstr

main :: IO ()
main = do
  lol <- nimoft
  Prelude.putStrLn "hello"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found the error, I changed the line of the call with :

```
(Right $ ConstantOperand $ GlobalReference (PointerType (FunctionType int [int, int] False) (A.AddrSpace 0)) (Name "subbing"))
```

Comment: I ran into the same problem -- here are some additional resources I found that were useful: (1) discussion about function calls https://github.com/llvm-hs/llvm-hs-examples/issues/2 , (2) example function call: https://gist.github.com/cocreature/93625b5afac68eb7de8b2eaa44561ab6